# Custom object detection model not detecting proper coordinates in Python script but working perfect in CLI

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, deep-learning, yolo

I have trained a custom object detection model using YOLOv8 to detect number/license plates in images. When I test the model using the command-line interface, it works fine and gives proper bounding box coordinates for the detected plates. However, when I use a Python script to get the bounding box coordinates and crop the image, the model is not detecting the coordinates properly.

## Using CLI (Working properly)

When I am using the CLI command of YOLOv8 to detect the licence-plate it is working properly.

```bash
yolo predict detect model=best.pt source=photo1.jpg save=True

# Output
Ultralytics YOLOv8.0.53  Python-3.9.16 torch-2.1.0.dev20230315 CPU
Model summary (fused): 168 layers, 11125971 parameters, 0 gradients, 28.4 GFLOPs

image 1/1
416x640 1 np, 115.0ms
Speed: 0.7ms preprocess, 115.0ms inference, 8.6ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
Results saved to runs/detect/predict
```

**Stored Output:**

[image]

## Using python script (Not working correctly)

When I am using the following python script - it is not extracting the correct image coordinates. I am using OpenCV to crop the number plate - but the model is not giving the right coordinates that can crop the image.

```py
import cv2
from ultralytics import YOLO

model = YOLO('best.pt')

image = cv2.imread('photo1.jpg')
result = model(image)

result = result[0].boxes
result = result.numpy()
print(result)

# print(result.boxes)  # print the box coordinates
[x,y,w,h] = result.xyxy.tolist()[0]  # print the box coordinates
print(x,y,w,h)
x, y, w, h = int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)

object = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow('Object', object)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```bash
# Output
0: 416x640 1 np, 130.3ms
Speed: 0.9ms preprocess, 130.3ms inference, 7.4ms postprocess per image at shape (1, 3, 640, 640)
[[     155.34      71.656       245.1      146.62     0.88172           0]]
155.33755493164062 71.65567779541016 245.10494995117188 146.61927795410156
```

**Cropped Image:**

[image]

---

Please help me to detect the root of this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this line of code:

```
[x,y,w,h] = result.xyxy.tolist()[0]
```

I think it's not mapped to `x, y, w, h` instead it's mapped to `xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax` because you invoke the `.xyxy` attribute from result object.

So, that is why you get the top left corner correct, but the bottom right corner too far. To fix that, you can modify that line and this line:

```py
object = image[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]
```

Hope that helps!